AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance unable to build draco
I'm trying to build OpenUSD with an Adobe plugin found here on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu. I get the following errors:
/home/ubuntu/USD_Adobe/src/draco-1.3.6/src/draco/core/hash_utils.h:27:1: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
   27 | size_t HashCombine(T1 a, T2 b) {
      | ^~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/USD_Adobe/src/draco-1.3.6/src/draco/core/hash_utils.h:21:1: note: ‘size_t’ is defined in header ‘<cstddef>’; did you forget to ‘#include <cstddef>’?
   20 | #include <functional>
  +++ |+#include <cstddef>
   21 | 
/home/ubuntu/USD_Adobe/src/draco-1.3.6/src/draco/core/hash_utils.h:34:1: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
   34 | size_t HashCombine(T a, size_t hash) {

/home/ubuntu/USD_Adobe/src/draco-1.3.6/src/draco/io/parser_utils.cc: In function ‘bool draco::parser::ParseFloat(draco::DecoderBuffer*, float*)’:
/home/ubuntu/USD_Adobe/src/draco-1.3.6/src/draco/io/parser_utils.cc:119:16: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
  119 |       v = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/USD_Adobe/src/draco-1.3.6/src/draco/io/parser_utils.cc:119:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
  119 |       v = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

I'm not sure how or what I can update to fix this. The build script seems to be using gmake for draco and my gmake version is 4.3. But I don't think it's the gmake version since numeric_limits was added to the std library before 4.3.
I would add the include statements to the relevant files but as you can see they are part of the build process, and it's probably better to fix the compile issue.

The plugin's readme says that Draco 1.5.6 (or “1.56”) is required and it has #include <cstddef> in hash_utils.h, see https://github.com/google/draco/blob/1.5.6/src/draco/core/hash_utils.h

Also parser_utils.cc in the new version has #include <limits> which should resolve the issue with numeric_limits

That tells me I shouldn't get these errors, not sure what's causing this.

Based on the path in your error messages you may have an older version.

But draco-1.3.6 is part of the build. I didn't choose the version manually.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the project the Adobe plugin you linked. I also didn't find the directory src/draco-1.3.6 in it. Is it part of some other project?
